# Symfony 2 multiple versions in the same app

Tags: symfony, design-patterns, containers

We have a symfony 2 project and the client wants 3 "little" different versions of the same app. I would want to avoid creating 3 branches and maintain them separately, so based on the client request I would want to ask you what do you think will be the best approach for that. I studied a little bit, but unsure about the best solution.

So, what client wants:

- `dynamic form fields + validation` - for every version I will have a different fields configuration. I'm deploying with capistrano, I have a post:deploy command I can hook into that to get fields settings. The problem here is that I have the install context just in that command 
  `--version=v1`. And I would need in all the app to have a  list [v1, v2, v3] and a current v2.  What is the best approach to inject a list and a current version in the container ?

Compiling the container with extra parameters ?

Different AppKernel versions ?

- `static php files` I can handle them using version in path to the files on the deploy command.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I think in the end it was a beginner question. Will declare in parameters a current_version variable, use it on code logic. And this variable will be overwritten on deploy command and should be ok. But for now I have just 3 versions, what if will have 10. Create 10 folders with different files, parse yml files 10 times etc.

Comment: Is it just the forms that are different?  I have some apps which build forms dynamically.  It's also possible that you might be able to use a different environment for each version: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html

Comment: For now just this, buy maybe in future it can extends to some Excel imports, static files, templates. Created a service with container  injected and I will add logic in this service to return what I need. And based on this service will do the logic in the code.